# rails: how to get all key-values from Rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I want to maintain an user online/offline list with Rails.cache(memory_store).

Basically if a request `/user/heartbeat?name=John` reached Rails server, it will simply:

```
def update_status
  name = params.require(:name)
  Rails.cache.write(name, Time.now.utc.iso8601, expires_in: 6.seconds)
end
```

But how could I get all the data stored in Rails.cache similarly as following?

```
def get_status
  # wrong codes, as Rails.cache.read doesn't have :all option.
  ary = Rails.cache.read(:all)
  # deal with array ...
end
```

I googled for a while, it seems Rails.cache doesn't provide the method to get all the data directly. Or there is better way to store the data?

I'm using `Rails 5.0.2`.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 27):

If you have redis you can use sth like `Rails.cache.redis.keys`

Answer (score 20):

You can get all keys with code:

```
keys = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
```

Comment: >> >> keys = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
keys = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: I test with rails 5.2.1 cause same error. You can try with `Rails.cache.redis.keys`

Comment: /!\ Be careful, it doesn't work with all cache backends: it works with `:memory_store` for example, but NOT for Redis (`:redis_cache_store`).

Comment: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers seem to work if you're using Redis. Instead, you will have to use redis-rb:

```rb
redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"])
redis.keys("*")
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can iterate on the keys to get their values and display them all

```
keys = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys
keys.each{|key| puts "key: #{key}, value: #{Rails.cache.fetch(key)}"}
```

or map them all directly as such:

```
key_values = Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys.map{|key| {key: key, value: Rails.cache.fetch(key)}}
```

In addition I would check beforehand the amount of keys to make sure I would not come up with a gigantic object (and if so, restrict the key_value array generated to the first 1000 items for instance). 
You could use:

```
Rails.cache.instance_variable_get(:@data).keys.count
```

or just look at the last line of the stats command:

```
Rails.cache.stats
```

Comment: /!\ Be careful, it doesn't work with all cache backends: it works with `:memory_store` for example, but NOT for Redis (`:redis_cache_store`).

Answer (score 1):

The above answeres helped me. The existing cache values can been seen by looping

```
 Rails.cache.redis.keys.each{ |k| puts k if Rails.cache.exist?(k)}
```